# catching exception in spring controller is advisable?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, exception

i had a argument with my manager regarding having generic exception catch in spring controller object

```
public class userController{

  public void addUser(@Model user UserObj){

         //call service and throws service exception(wrap database exception in service layer)
    catch (ServiceException sExp){
        log error here
        redirect error page;
   } catch (Exception ecp) {
       redirect error or log error for reference;
   }
}
```

with the above code i had conflict with my manager, saying that you should not have exception block , only service exception in controller.But i have argued for worst case scenario we can have exception which will catch un-noticed business exception and log the error.

i think having exception is not bad idea. what will be the consequences if i have exception block at only controller level.

Comment: catching exceptions to avoid application crash is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should not handle unexpected exceptions in the controller. If you want to log unexpected exceptions, then use a global exception handler that will do that for all the exceptions of all the controller methods. That will centralize the exception handling, prevent massive code duplication, and avoid cluttering your controller methods.

Look at the `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler` annotations.

Comment: centralizing exception handling should handle exception also, shouldnt it?, so i should catch exception rite here? no answer for tat part!!!!

Comment: Have you read the documentation of ControllerAdvice and ExceptionHandler? An ExceptionHandler will be invoked if the controller doesn't catch the exception that the ExceptionHandler handles.